# Showing that $\mathbb{P}^n \cong k^n \cup k^{n-1} \cup ... \cup k^1 \cup k^0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

Given that $\mathbb{P}$ is the projective space over $k$ and $k$ is an algebraically closed field.

Comment: What have you attempted thus far? And by the way, you can similarly write that $$\mathbb{P}^n\cong \bigcup_{i=0}^n k^i$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show that $\mathbb{P}^n = k^n \cup \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ by looking at coordinates - you don't need algebraically closed.